# iOS9 Causing iPhone 5 Optimization to be lost

Tags: ios, ios8, splash-screen, ios9, autoresize

**EDIT To clarify question**

I have a large app that has been out for a few years.  It runs perfect on all iPhone sizes (4 up to the 6 plus).  It supports both iOS 7 & iOS8, and is Optimized for iPhone 5.

My issue is with iOS9.  The app no longer uses the built in scaling that iOS provided to fit the app onto the 6 or 6P screens.

Not only that, but it is rendered as if it were on a 3.5" screen. It is not recognizing the Default-568h@2x.png static image. Causing it to letterbox on an iPhone 5.

Is this a bug in iOS9 that does not recognize the static splash screen image?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You should really change you app to support a more dynamic layout, so it can handle to new screen dimensions. Apple already changed there policy that you had to support the iPhone 5 resolution.

Comment: Totally agree, and that is part of the plan.  But right now we need a solution.  To have the app just stop working on all devices is definitely not something we expected.. as all iOS releases have been completely backward compatible.

Comment: Well I got an app reject for not having 4" inch support some time ago, I guess that will not reject you app for not supporting 4.7" and/or 5.5". I'm using static images for my app and it is working when building with Xcode 7 or 6. But I am support all resolutions.

Comment: That's the weird thing.  I am including static splash images.  And it works fine on all device sizes.. except for with iOS9.  When we run the current app from the store on an iOS9 iPhone 5S, the screen is letterboxed as if it were on a 3.5" screen.  Which tells me that when people start upgrading tomorrow, the app is going to look terrible.  Any thoughts?

Comment: One additional thing.  My current package in the app store only has the 4" default splash image.  So this explains why the stock scaling works for iPhone 6 and 6 plus in iOS8.  The weird thing is that the 4" rendering no longer works in iOS9..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by my Default-568h@2x.png file being localized (Which is required by iTunes Connect).

When I removed the localization from the file, it started rendering perfect in iOS9.

This does not help anyone whose app is currently in the store with a localized Default-568h@2x splash screen file.

As far as I can tell the only way around it is to have a 'Splash Screen' .xib file defined in your project settings (you then lose the auto scaling for iPhone 6 and 6+, which was perfect for our application).

I have a case open with Apple regarding this.  They told me that they could not look deeper into it until iOS9 was out of Beta (tomorrow morning), and if it was still happening, than it is indeed a bug on their side and (hopefully) would be fixed soon.

Comment: any news about this issue ? I am in the same case: launch screen localized and I need to keep the auto scaling for iPhone 6/6+ .. any solution ?

Comment: Only solution is to build and submit in Xcode 6.4.  You can develop and test on iPhone 6/6+ devices still.. you just need to open Xcode 7.3 with the device attached, open a project and let it index the files.  Once that is done close Xcode 7.3 and open Xcode 6.4.  Then you can resume as normal.  Eventually (soon) this option will surely be gone.. so start adapting your app to auto resize.  Total pain when the built in auto resizing worked perfect.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I use Images.xcassets to manage assets of app. I had to create a LaunchImage in there and just add images for iphone Portrait ios 7-9 and not have any for retina 4.7 and retina 5.5 and things worked again.

If you use a Launch Storyboard then you need to remove that and add xcassets as mentioned in previous paragraph

This is in xcode 7